# How when testing React Component in Jest I can wait until receives props again?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I need to test a HOC which fetches data and passes it to a wrapped component.

It passes props in a few steps as data is fetched asynchronously.

First wave of props contains `loading` , which I managed to test

Second wave of props contains `data` prop, but I don't know to wait untill it arrives. I need some sort of `eventuallyHasProps` thing..

I am using Jest, react-test-renderer.

Is there any way to achieve this avoiding setting manual timeouts?

Thanks

```
it(
  "first fetch results should be discarded",
  () => {
    // jest.useFakeTimers();

    const fetchMock = jest
      .fn()
      .mockImplementationOnce(() => {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve(reqSuccess("slow")), 1000));
      })
      .mockImplementationOnce(() => {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve(reqSuccess("fast")), 100));
      });

    const options = {
      url: props => `http://test.com${props.testArg}`,
      fetchApi: fetchMock
    };

    const WithFetch = withFetch(options)(component);

    // first request
    const testRenderer = renderer.create(<WithFetch />);

    // second request
    testRenderer.update(<WithFetch testArg="test" />);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const resultTree = testRenderer.toTree();
        resolve(expect(resultTree.rendered.props.data.data.result).toBe("fast"));
      }, 4000);
    });

    // jest.runAllTimers();
  },
  5000
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options, use an async test:

```
it("should receive data prop", async () => {
  const someresult = await <Promise call>     
  const secondresult = await <Promise call>     
  expect(someresult).toHaveBeenCalledWith(something);
});
```

Or return a promise:

```
it("should receive data prop", () => {
  return new Promise(resolve=> {
       // Your assertions (don't forget to call resolve)
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, in the end I landed on a second options  with a setTimeout inside a promise, but still looking for a better solution

Comment: I think `async`/`await` is really nice solution, not sure what you mean by a better solution, let me know :-)

Comment: hi! yes async/await is nice, but it still doesn't free from a setTimeout, or I don't know how to achieve that. I have updated the post just now. You see I have a hoc that does an async request internally. When the request is finished the hoc passes new props. I looking for a way of registering somehow that a new set of props was passed (component was updated). I used setTimeout but that is rediculous

Comment: actually, I have just thought - maybe I can wrap a wrapped component with another hoc which will have a spy inside. yes that should work.. thanks!! it is always nice to formulate a question as it helps to direct thoughts..

Comment: but I still don't know how to get rid of setTimeout =\

Comment: Using a timeout is perfectly normal if you need to wait for something to happen in a test, but you can ask yourself if this is needed in this situation. A unit test, tests behaviour of the component. You want to ignore the first request when the second was received before the first was returned. Why not call them in order synchronously? This is actually what the component is receiving (with some time delay)

Comment: Hi Dennie. Thanks for the answer. I think you are right in saying that actually the approach to testing in this case should be different. I should really think about it. Thanks. Here I don't want to ignore request, but I need to assess the second set of props that a HOC will set on a wrapped component. (an third and fourth an so on). The first set is set synchronously , but the second secont time props a set after componentDidMount occured.. It looks like the wrapped component could be a stub (sinon) and a generator and just yield every time the props change. That is a bit complicated though..

Answer (score 0):

Try using done() as mentioned here: https://alligator.io/testing/asynchronous-testing-jest/ 
Worked for me! And no timers.